# Custom taskbar icon layout aesthetics

Tags: windows, taskbar, icons

Today I realized I can add a custom taskbar to Windows which would be a folder full of shortcuts to common tasks.

I created the folder, added the taskbar, and thought 'eh this could be pretty nice'.. I'll be adding at least a dozen things here..

[image]

Then I clicked "lock all taskbars" and realized...

[image]

***Of course...*** The layout changed slightly and now the first icon (cmd shortcut) is half cut off. I let my guard down, underestimating Windows' ability to disappoint in such small but such irritating ways.

Is there a way to make a custom toolbar more aesthetic? There's no way my brain will tolerate the distraction of a half-visible icon on the toolbar...

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, and will suffice, but doesn't allow me to place the toolbar where I want:

If I add the toolbar and do not change the size/location (default location is flush-right on taskbar, near system tray) then the toolbar doesn't have the half-icon:

[image]

But if I attempt to relocate/resize them, Windows shows its true colors:

[image]

Not ideal. But sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Really making a taskbar aesthetic? Right click on the taskbar, Unlock it, right click on the toolbar title and uncheck show text , then right click again on the, toolbar title and uncheck show title

Comment: `"Really making a taskbar aesthetic?"` Am I supposed to regret wanting things to look good? I'm confused by that question / second-guessing. Also, your solution `"Uncheck show title"` doesn't work.